# sql order by with group by rollup

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

My query looks like below with the foll. output

Current Output

```
Role            Cases prepped % Completed    
State Member 1  10    5       50%
State Member 2  10    7       70%
State President 10    2       20%
Summary         30    14      46.6%
```

Output Expected

```
Role            Cases prepped % Completed
State President 10    2       20%
State Member 1  10    5       50%
State Member 2  10    7       70%
Summary         30    14      46%
```

Roles table

```
id name
30 State President
40 State Member
```

This is my query,

```
SELECT COALESCE(ROLE, 'Summary') ROLE,   
       count(*) AS cases, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS prepped, 
 round(avg(case when prepared = 'Y' then 100 else 0 end),2)||'%' as % Completed
FROM
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name
              ELSE r.name || ' ' || u.case_member_id
          END AS ROLE,
          bi.prepared
   FROM cases c
   LEFT JOIN case_inventory ci ON ci.case_id = c.id
   AND c.id = ci.case_id
   AND c.delete_date IS NULL
   AND ci.case_id =40
  Left JOIN users u ON ci.assigned_to = u.id
   Left JOIN ROLES r ON u.role_id = r.id
   Left JOIN user_cases_map uc ON c.id = uc.case_id
   AND uc.id = 1572919346)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (ROLE);
```

I now want to order the rows with respect to the role. The 1st record should be the State president and then followed by state memebr 1. state member 2. and so on. I tried to have an order by in the inner clause but it did not help. It doesnt have any effect. Adding in the outer select also doesnt change anything. Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: "My query looks like..." is never a good **first** line when you ask a question. Start with the data - in this case, perhaps, with the **output** of your query. Tell us what it looks like, and what else you need to add to it. We can read your query, and - assuming it is correct - we may guess what the output might look like, but why should we have to do all this extra work, when you can tell us outright?

Comment: @mathguy sorry i have updated my question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Starting from your current query, you can just use `avg()`:

```
SELECT 
    COALESCE(ROLE, 'Summary') ROLE,   
    COUNT(*) AS cases, 
    SUM(CASE WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS prepped, 
    AVG(CASE WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS ratio_completed
FROM ...
```

This returns a numeric between `0` and `1`. You can replace `THEN 1` with `THEN 100` if you prefer a percentage (between `0` and `100`).

Comment: it worked . Thank you. Please find the updated question. Can you please help with the order by in this case.

Answer (score 1):

It is a good practice in SQL to split a more complex logic in several subqueries.

I'll recomend to use one subquery (basically your query) to calculate the counts and *an other* subquery to calculate the ratio.

The new main  query would be

```
select ROLE, CASES, PREPPED,
(PREPPED/nullif(CASES,0))* 100 proc_completed
from (your query);

ROLE                 CASES    PREPPED PROC_COMPLETED
--------------- ---------- ---------- --------------
State President         10          2             20
State Member 1          10          5             50
State Member 2          10          7             70
State Member 2           0          0               
Summary                 10         14            140
```

Note that I added a new line with the edge case of count = 0 and I use the [nullif](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/20/sqlrf/NULLIF.html#GUID-445FC268-7FFA-4850-98C9-D53D88AB2405) function to avoid problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use just `count(*)` where you currently have `sum(count(*))` in your expression for `comp`.