# sql order by with an inner select clause and group by rollup

Tags: sql, oracle

My query looks like below with the foll. output

Current Output

```
Role            Cases prepped % Completed    
State Member 1  10    5       50%
State Member 2  10    7       70%
State President 10    2       20%
Summary         30    14      46.6%
```

Output Expected

```
Role            Cases prepped % Completed
State President 10    2       20%
State Member 1  10    5       50%
State Member 2  10    7       70%
Summary         30    14      46%
```

Roles table

```
id name
30 State President
40 State Member
```

This is my query,

```
SELECT COALESCE(ROLE, 'Summary') ROLE,   
       count(*) AS cases, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN PREPARED = 'Y' THEN 1
                ELSE 0
           END) AS prepped, 
 round(avg(case when prepared = 'Y' then 100 else 0 end),2)||'%' as % Completed
FROM
  (SELECT CASE
              WHEN r.id = 30 THEN r.name
              ELSE r.name || ' ' || u.case_member_id
          END AS ROLE,
          bi.prepared
   FROM cases c
   LEFT JOIN case_inventory ci ON ci.case_id = c.id
   AND c.id = ci.case_id
   AND c.delete_date IS NULL
   AND ci.case_id =40
  Left JOIN users u ON ci.assigned_to = u.id
   Left JOIN ROLES r ON u.role_id = r.id
   Left JOIN user_cases_map uc ON c.id = uc.case_id
   AND uc.id = 1572919346)
GROUP BY ROLLUP (ROLE);
```

I now want to order the rows with respect to the role. The 1st record should be the State president and then followed by state memebr 1. state member 2. and so on. I tried to have an order by in the inner clause but it did not help. It doesnt have any effect. Adding in the outer select also doesnt change anything. Any help highly appreciated. Thank you.

Comment: What is the relation between the ID in the ROLES table and the desired order of your query's output? If lower ID means higher priority (must appear first in the output), order by the ID at the end. And to keep things neat (to always have the summary at the end), use the GROUPING function (in ORDER BY, but you can also use it in SELECT, in a CASE expression, instead of COALESCE)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [sql order by with group by rollup](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64610906/sql-order-by-with-group-by-rollup)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do something like this. I don't have your input data, so I used `SCOTT.EMP` instead.

Notice a few things. I grouped by `JOB`, and I used `GROUPING(JOB)` both in `SELECT` (to add the label `TOTAL` for the summary row) and in `ORDER BY`. Since I reuse the column name `JOB` in `SELECT` (for the output column), in `ORDER BY` I must be careful to qualify the column name `JOB` (to make it clear I am referring to the input table column, not to the column in `SELECT` - which would be the default if column names in `ORDER BY` were not qualified). The need to qualify column names in `ORDER BY`, then, forced me to alias the table in the `FROM` clause (otherwise I would have had to carry the full table name everywhere).

Using the `GROUPING` function in `SELECT` (rather than `NVL`) is particularly important if `JOB` can be `null`. You don't want the group for `null` job to be labeled `TOTAL` - you only want that for the rollup row. This point confuses even a lot of very advanced programmers.

I show how you can "manually" decide the order: `PRESIDENT` first, then `MANAGER`, and then all other jobs (ordered alphabetically). If you have the order of priority saved somewhere, for example in a table, you can join to that table and use the ordering column instead of the "manual" `CASE` expression in my query.

```
select case grouping(job) when 0 then job else 'TOTAL' end as job
     , sum(sal) as total_salary
from   scott.emp e
group  by rollup(job)
order  by grouping(e.job)       -- to get the total in the last row
        , case e.job when 'PRESIDENT' then 1 when 'MANAGER' then 2 end
        , e.job
;

JOB       TOTAL_SALARY
--------- ------------
PRESIDENT         5000
MANAGER           8275
ANALYST           6000
CLERK             4150
SALESMAN          5600
TOTAL            29025
```

Comment: that is great . I added case to the order by clause and it sort of worked. Please see my updated question.

Comment: the reason im adding as a different thread is im unable to edit my question